# List of restored variables in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Before I restore values of the variables from the ckpt file, I need to create these variables in the file where I restore the variables. Yet in this new file, there can be some other variables that are not in the ckpt file. Is it possible to print just a list of variables that are restored (tf.all_variables would not work in this case)?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're doing in your new file? Are you adding new variables and saving again?

Comment: Here, I just wanted to get a list of variables that are saved in a given ckpt file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`inspect_checkpoint.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py) tool to list the variables in your checkpoint you are restoring.

```py
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file

# List ALL tensors.
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name='./model.ckpt', tensor_name='')

# List contents of a specific tensor.
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name='./model.ckpt', tensor_name='conv1_w')
```

Another method:

```py
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader('./model.ckpt')
var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
for key in var_to_shape_map:
    print("tensor_name: ", key)
    print(reader.get_tensor(key)) # Remove this is you want to print only variable names
```

List all global variables from current graph:

```py
for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES):
    print(v)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of variables that can be saved, I believe you can use this:

`tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) + tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS)`

Answer (score 1):

use
`print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name, tensor_name, all_tensors)`

Args:
    file_name: Name of the checkpoint file.
    tensor_name: Name of the tensor in the checkpoint file to print.
    all_tensors: Boolean indicating whether to print all tensors.